# How to make a Standalone QGIS application run as an exe file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, standalone

I had made a simple standalone application and that works fine. But the user have to execute a batch file(inside in which I had set the QGISHOME path, Python path and call my main python file) to run the application. I am assuming there are ways to execute the application as an EXE file. If so what are the steps to convert to exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using pyinstaller: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki
It will  require some tweeking to get all the dependencies.

Comment: Well Thanks warrieka. Will try with the pyinstaller then.